# view centered above in between weight distributed views in linear layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I am trying to achieve a layout as follows:

[image: floating button above]

Two views with weight 2(green View) & 1(blue View) in a linear layout. And a floating button centered in between those views infront of them. But it is not possible using linear layout. Can anyone give a little help here

Update:
Here is what I have done

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="#22B14C" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="To be a floating button" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#00A2E8" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And what  I got is

[image: floating button between]

Comment: You should add example code so that we can more easily answer the question.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to [CoordinatorLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.html) in the [Design Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html) this problem can be solved.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/top"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:background="#22B14C" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/bottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#00A2E8" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:backgroundTint="#a349a4"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/top"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

You have to anchor the FloatingActionButton to the top view using `layout_anchor` attribute and then set anchor gravity using `layout_anchorGravity`

And here is what you get:

[image: solution image]

Comment: When trying to do it like this I get this error:  **java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$LayoutParams** do you have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can do this if you want to use the `LinearLayout` the way you use it is to define fixed height for the button. You can then achieve the overlay like this

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="-24dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-24dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="To be a floating button"/>
```

But since it is not a good practice to use layout weights I would suggest to switch to `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: This way the half of button seems to go behind the lower view. Using relative layout is of course a good way. But I don't see a simple way of achieving it.