# Android layout: place a view between two views

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, overlap, android-layout-weight

I am trying to make a screen, preferably with XML only, to look like this:
[image]

I followed [this approach,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26688395/2819864) but using FrameLayout I only have the option to position the "orange" view using `layout_gravity`, and as I try to explain in the image, I don't know the layouts' height, because both measure with layout_weight.

My layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="onit.radiolisten.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_container_activity_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <!-- TOP LAYOUT, THE GREEN ONE ON THE IMAGE -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_top_activity_main"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>

            <!-- BOTTOM LAYOUT, THE BLUE ONE ON THE IMAGE -->
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#e6e6e6">

            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- THIS IS THE IMAGE I WANT TO POSITION -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btn_play_radio"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/play_icon" />
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Can this be done with XML only?

Comment: Follow this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30244020/view-centered-above-in-between-weight-distributed-views-in-linear-layout). I think this is the appropriate which you want

Comment: Follow another [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26578418/android-place-an-image-view-between-two-views). Hope it will help you

Comment: Thanks @Masum, I resolved following the approach on the first link!

Answer (score 9):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<--main layout-->      
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
<--top layout-->
    <LinearLayout    
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:gravity="bottom|center"/>

   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:background="@color/callingscreen_color"
        android:gravity="center|top" />     
    </LinearLayout>
<--layout for img-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

      <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="0dp"
          android:layout_weight="1.5" >
      </LinearLayout>

      <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="0dp"
          android:layout_weight="0.5" 
          android:gravity="center|top">
<--IMage u want to put-->
          <ImageView
              android:id="@+id/ivimg"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:src="@drawable/img"/>
      </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: this works quite nice for full-height screens but if used for dialog it takes the whole screen height

Comment: Well I'd just say "Quite Creative" Works well! Although I didn't need the same design but similar. And it was good to get me started, and achieve that! Nice!
But this only works if the screen is static and not :
* A dialog
* A view with scrollable content.

Comment: Absolutely it is for static full-height screens. Works for me, Hope for others also.

Answer (score 0):

I came here looking for answers to the same question but I found nothing as well as other posts. Then, I realized I had to figure a way out myself.
The below employs the use of weights and margin.

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?colorSecondary"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="11"
    tools:context=".ActivityUserAccount">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="10"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-90dp"
        android:background="@drawable/sample_user"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/sample_user" />

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-50dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#FFFAFA"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="50dp">

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Output]